# CoreData manual ordering

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data

I parse json after use coreDate save , tableViewCell show coreData items .

I click tableViewCell data sender to another page.

I want click coreData can sort by click.

Does anyone know a solution please?

thank you very much

My English is very poor, I hope you don't take offense

```
  var corePlayVideo = [CoreVideo]()
  var likeVideo = [CoreVideo]()


 @IBAction func likeButtonPress(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        corePlayVideo[sender.tag].isLike = !corePlayVideo[sender.tag].isLike
   
        coreData.saveContext()

        if corePlayVideo[sender.tag].isLike == true {
            
            likeVideo.append(corePlayVideo[sender.tag])
            coreData.saveContext()
            sendLikeData()
            
        } else {
            
            for i in 0 ..< likeVideo.count {
                
                if corePlayVideo[sender.tag].cVideoId == likeVideo[i].cVideoId {

                    likeVideo.remove(at: i)

                    sendLikeData()
                    coreData.saveContext()
                    break
                    
                }
            }
        }
        
        
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0)], with: .none)
    }
```

I check information，coreData have fixed order，because NSFetchRequest.

I want coreData sort by click, what should I do?

thank you very much

Comment: You can of course sort the array (corePlayVideo?) anyway you want after it has been loaded with values from Core Data so I don't understand your claim about the order being fixed.

Comment: I want click one corePlayVideo，it will append to likeVideo array, sender likeVideo array to other page. click the second corePlayVideo, it also  append to likeVideo array. likeVideo array page can sort click first、second